# How to remove Clementine alternate list background colors? (Qt5)

Tags: qt, colors, qt5, clementine

Like Dolphin, Clementine usually has alternating background colors in lists that look like this in the track view frame:

[image]

I would like to remove those alternating colors to have a clear view of the album art in the background.

So far, I've not been able to remove them. I installed `qt5ct` and can change their color with a custom color scheme by editing the Alternate background/Inactive color, but the "Alpha channel" value does not seem to make a difference.

Then, I tried to add a custom stylesheet with `QListView {alternate-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);}`, which changes the Qt5ct-interface lists, but not the Clementine track selection backgrounds.

I don't know how to find out what value the Alternate background/Inactive color in Qt5ct is referring to or how to remove the alternating backgrounds otherwise.

Unfortunately, setting all background colors in the same tone doesn't work in Clementine because of the layering: Window background - Album cover - List item backgrounds, so it will still be visible.

Is there any way to remove those backgrounds?

Comment: Hi, it's version 1.3.1 from the main repository and on Xfce.

Comment: Okay, I don't use it but that version seems to be using `qt4`, not `qt5`, so you may want to look into that.

Comment: Uhm, the About Qt - Help page says it's 5.12.4 and I doubt Qt5ct would work on version 4 at all, would it?

Comment: That's true and I can't explain it. But if you look at `apt depends clementine` for the version mentioned, there are `qt4` dependencies but no qt5 dependency. So it's quite a mystery (to me).